# Uploading files with codeigniter (3.1) fails

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with uploading files with Codeigniter framework. 
Currently is working like this:
If i don't select any file in HTML form, then variables like `$title = $this->input->post('title');` gets value,
but when i select file in html form, then all variables are null and i get message file is not selected.

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My autoload.php file

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'form');
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'email', 'form_validation');
$autoload['model'] = array('model_services' => 'ms', 'Model_categories' => 'mc');
```

My controller which is rendering view:

```
 public function add_catalog() {
        if ($this->is_admin() == TRUE) {
            $data['cat'] = $this->mc->get();
            $this->load->view('admin_view_map/admin_header');
            $this->load->view('admin_view_map/admin_add_catalog', $data);
            $this->load->view('admin_view_map/admin_footer');
        } else {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin321/insert_catalog'); ?>
    *title: <input type="text" name="title" />
    sub_title: <input type="text" name="sub_title" />
    Facebook url: <input type="text" name="facebookUrl" />
    Twitter url: <input type="text" name="twitterUrl" />
    Google +: <input type="text" name="googlePlus" />
    description: <input type="text" name="description" />
    pdf: </span> <input type="file" name="pdf" />
    categories:
    <select name="categories" >
        <?php foreach ($cat as $r) {
                echo '<option value=' . $r->id_category . ' >' . $r->category . '</option>';
        } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

PHP:

```
public function insert_catalog(){
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $sub_title = $this->input->post('sub_title');
    $facebookUrl = $this->input->post('facebookUrl');
    $twitterUrl = $this->input->post('twitterUrl');
    $googlePlus = $this->input->post('googlePlus');
    $description = $this->input->post('description');
    $category = $this->input->post('categories');
    var_dump($title,$sub_title,$facebookUrl,$twitterUrl,$googlePlus,$description,$category);

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/pdf/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pdf')){
        var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
        die();
    }else{
        $pdf = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        var_dump($pdf);
        die();
    }

}
```

This make result like this:

```
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
string '<p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>' (length=43)
```

I'm using WAMP server and this are my php.ini configuration

```
; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = "e:/wamp/tmp"

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Comment: does `$_FILES` contain anything?

Comment: if i place var_dump($_FILES); in my controller function i get array (size=0) empty

Comment: can you post the method thats rendering the form? Also, why are the `input` values set to `post` data?

Comment: no method is rendering HTML form... just plain HTML. input values are for case if form fails so data stays in input

Comment: There **HAS** to be a method rendering the view...

Comment: I disagree! if i don't select file in html form then i get some results in var_dump.... string 'title' (length=3) string 'sub title' (length=3)... so problem must be in selecting/uploading files

Comment: You dont seem to understand...theres a controller somewhere rendering the view that contains the html thats shows the form. Anyhow, I suggest you try to add some XSS settings since you're attempting to upload a pdf  `$this->upload->set_xss_clean(TRUE);`

Comment: Oh yes now i know what did you wan't.
I have updated my question

Comment: Can you add your `.htaccess` please? Are you able to upload ANY kind of file? Have you checked php's upload settings?

Comment: I believe that all root cause for this problem is $this->input->post('pdf') returns null

Comment: check your php installation settings.

Comment: problem was in post_max_size = 3M and my pdf was 3.15M :/ thx for halp enyway

Comment: @Kisaragi Can you please answer question and i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your php's installation settings  in php.ini regarding upload configuration

```
upload_max_filesize  = 10M
post_max_size  = 10M
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get it.

```
<?php foreach ($cat as $r) {
        echo '<option value=' . $r->id_category . ' >' . $r->category . '</option>';
} ?>
```

What are you echoing here ?
Where do you get $cat from ?

Comment: This is working fine...
just some categories objects
 0 => 
    object(stdClass)[25]
      public 'id_category' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'category' => string 'cooling' (length=8)
      public 'parrent_category' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 =>........

Comment: could be a variable passed from the method that's rendering the form view.

Comment: I have updated my question with method redering view

Comment: problem was in post_max_size = 3M in php.ini setting

Answer (score 1):

Load `form helper` on your controller

```
function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');

}
```

Comment: Form helper is autoloaded in autoload.php
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'form');